# JSON file Creation and adding nodes to JSON Tree type structure

Tags: java, json

I write an application which creates a JSON File following the below structure:

```
{
  identifier:"id",
label:"name",
items:[
  {
     id:"ROOT",
     name:"Parent1",
     type:"ROOT",
     children:[
        {
           _reference:"CHILD1"
        }
     ]
  },
  {
     id:"CHILD1",
     name:"Parent1-Child1",
     type:"Child",
     children:[
        {
           _reference:"CHILD2"
        }
     ]
  },
  {
     id:"CHILD2",
     name:"Child1-Child2",
     type:"Child",
     children:[
        {
           _reference:"Child3"
        },
        {
           _reference:"Child4"
        }
     ]
  },
  {
     id:"Child3",
     name:"Child2-Child3",
     type:"GrandChild"
  },
  {
     id:"Child4",
     name:"Child2-Child4",
     type:"GrandChild"
  },

]
}
```

So my application actually gets following data for each node of this JSON Tree

PID-- It to which i have to attach the child node
CID-- ID of Child Node
CNAME-- Child Node Name
CTYPE-- Child Type

So currently what i am doing is searching the PID in the json file through iterating ( on file system) and once i find the String which has id=PID,i append a Child Ref to that Node

```
    {
       _reference:"CHILD-NEXT"
    }
```

and then after this line adding the whole new child node

```
{
 id:"CHILD-NEXT",
 name:"Parent1-ChildNext",
 type:"Child",
},
```

But this is very inefficient solution because of iterating the file every time to search the parent node and appending/inserting the child.

So i am looking for a kind of solution in which i just create this JSON structure in memory and when i am done with adding all the nodes then i can write it to the file. I am doing this in JAVA,so i am looking for some existing JSON Libraries which i can use to fulfil this requirement.

Please comment if you need any other information of the above explanation is not clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [org.json](http://www.json.org/java/) library to do this.

You first need to read your json file into a `JSONObject` which is basically made up of key/value pairs and arrays. You can then loop over the items in the object, look for a pid and add a new child.

Here is some sample code to get you started:

```
//read file        
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("path/json.txt"));
String line;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
while((line =in.readLine()) != null){
    sb.append(line);
}
in.close();


//create a json object
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(sb.toString());

//pid to search for
String pid = "XXX";

//loop over the items array and look for pid
JSONArray items = json.getJSONArray("items");
for(int i = 0 ; i < items.length(); i++){
    JSONObject item = items.getJSONObject(i);
    String id = item.getString("id");
    if(pid.equals(id)){

        //get the children
        JSONArray children;
        if(item.has("children")){
            children = item.getJSONArray("children");    
        }
        else{
            children = new JSONArray();
            item.put("children", children);
        }

        //append a new child ref to the children
        JSONObject ref = new JSONObject();
        ref.put("_reference", "CHILD-NEXT");
        children.put(ref);

        //create a new child node
        JSONObject newItem = new JSONObject();
        newItem.put("id", "CHILD-NEXT");
        newItem.put("name", "Parent1-ChildNext");
        newItem.put("type", "Child");
        items.put(newItem);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot dogbane,it indeed help me to get the required solution.

Answer (score 1):

From JSON.org you have [JSON in Java](http://www.json.org/java/) that will provide you an in-memory JSON representation that you can manipulate and then write.

[This StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/338586/a-better-java-json-library) has a whole list of JSON libraries for Java, including [google-gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/), [JSONlib](http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/), [FlexJSON](http://flexjson.sourceforge.net/), [Jackson](http://www.cowtowncoder.com/hatchery/jackson/index.html), [json-simple](http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/), and [yet more on this blog review](http://www.rojotek.com/blog/2009/05/07/a-review-of-5-java-json-libraries/).

Depending on whether you are focused on full-featured, lightweight, or fast, you may find one or the other more suited to your needs.